# Ubuntu touch click package

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development

I have just publish my first app on Ubuntu touch. It is called "Food additives". Application can be install through ubuntu app store, but there is an one problem.

After app installation, you can see the app launcher in Apps list, but when you press and hold app launcher, you should be redirected to Ubuntu store and you should see information about the app. But I can see only option to uninstall and open. Ubuntu store still show me, than app Food additives is not installed on my phone, but it is.

I thing, that this is same problem with app name or something like that.

The name of my project in qt creator is: "ecka". my desktop and manifest files:
ecka.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Food additives  
Exec=qmlscene $@ ecka/Main.qml
Icon=ecka/ecka.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application 
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true
```

manifest.json.in

```
{
"name": "additives",
"description": "Food addditives ",
"architecture": "@CLICK_ARCH@",
"title": "Food additives",
"hooks": {
    "ecka": {
        "apparmor": "ecka/ecka.apparmor",
        "desktop": "ecka/ecka.desktop"
    }
},
"version": "0.1.2",
"maintainer": "FirstName LastName <firstName.lastName@gmail.com>",
"framework": "ubuntu-sdk-15.04"
```

}

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to edit out your email address so as to prevent your email from being scraped and harvested by spammers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is caused by your application name.  Right now, this should be of the form `<appname>.<username>`.  `<appname>` can be whatever you like ("additives" is perfectly fine), while `<username>` is your "developer namespace" on developer.ubuntu.com.  ([This page](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/account/) should list it.)  Remember, this value must be the same in the manifest file and as the applicationName in the main QML file.

I find it rather odd that they let you submit an app with these values set incorrectly.  I'll investigate and report a bug if appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I managed to repair my application  and now It works fine.